# WHM / Cpanel : Create and download backups for all accounts?

Tags: linux, backup

Is this possible? I want to download a standard cpanel full backup of every account on my server. There's about 15 accounts. Each are about 50-500 megs. It takes me about 3 hours every week to do this and I'd like to automate this process or at least do it in batch so it takes less time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this from within WHM, go to backup & restore, and there is the ability to backup and download all accounts?

Alternativley, if you use virtuozzo on your server, you could create a compelte server backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can either just write a script that will do this for you or use services like backupsetc.com which allow you to automatically backup your accounts within their infrastructure and then you can get them from there any time you want, and it's fully automated.

Answer (score -1):

You can upload all you backups to an FTP server using the cpanel backup wizards.
This option is available on both cpanel and WHM.